# Converting list to comma separated integers to be substituted in IN clause of Pandas dataframe query

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of integers that contains EMPI_ID

```
emp_list = [1,2]
```

I have a variable that defines the SQL query

```
emp_sql = '''
select 
      emp_id
    , emp_name
from emp
where emp in (%s)
'''
```

Columns for the dataframe:

```
emp_columns = [emp_id, emp_name]
```

When I try to convert them to comma separated integer values, the sql_string hold Str values and is failing to fetch the data from database.

```
emp = ','.join(emp_list)
sql_string = emp_sql%(emp)    
data = connection.fetchall(sql_string) 
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data, columns=emp_columns)
```

Please advise how i can change the query to substitute the IN clause of SQL with list of integers. from_records does not have param as parameter to pass the joined sql string.

Comment: The line `emp = ','.join(emp_list)` should throw an error already... is there something missing from the example?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Am not sure how to split them as comma separated integers. I tried that and it failed in that step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

list comprehension is you friend

```
emp_sql = f'''
select 
      emp_id
    , emp_name
from emp
where emp in (%s)
'''%(", ".join([str(i) for i in emp_list]))

print(emp_sql)
```

output:

```
select 
      emp_id
    , emp_name
from emp
where emp in (1, 2)
```

join only works with `str`, so you have to convert the elements in the list, thats where you can use list comprehension. With the join, you can enter them into the query.

**EDIT:** if you want the numbers quoted, try this

```
emp_sql = f'''
select 
      emp_id
    , emp_name
from emp
where emp in (%s)
'''%(", ".join([f"'{i}'" for i in emp_list]))

print(emp_sql)
```

giving this output:

```
select 
      emp_id
    , emp_name
from emp
where emp in ('1', '2')
```

Comment: Thank you ! Let me try this and get back.

Comment: Hi !  The columns that i am searching against is a VARCHAR datatype column. I would like to have the SQL in the following way ```select 
      emp_id
    , emp_name
from emp
where emp in ('1', '2')```. 1 and 2 enclosed within quotes. How can i achieve this?

Comment: @vvazza I edited the answer regarding your last question...